# Virtual box 'Seamless mode' leads to unresponsive guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

**Env**

- Ubuntu 16.04(Host)
- Windows 10(Guest)
- Virtual box 5.0.20 r106931

**Problem**

Whenever I enter into ***seamless mode*** from guest Win 10, the guest OS becomes unresponsive with some black screen.

Only way to recover is to Power off of the Win 10 guest, and restart the guest.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to Boot into seamless mode.  I have experienced the same issue and the only solution that I was able to work out was starting the machine in seamless mode.  This is not convenient for me as the VM keeps running.

Comment: May I know how to start the machine in seamless mode? If it works I'll mark the above as answer.